# trying to create a large text file consist of zeros and ones (binary)

Tags: file, binary

how to create a large binary text file ( consist of 0 or 1 randomly) ? tried doing that in eclipse , it got stuck...

I just need a file of size 100KB txt of 0 and 1 randomly..

Comment: What platform, e.g. Windows/Linux/MacOS?

Comment: Random bits?  Or random characters '0' and '1'?

Comment: Please provide the code you tried in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Eclipse, I'm assuming you're writing in Java. And I'm also assuming that you want 100 kilobytes of random *character* 0s and 1s, *not bytes*.

Here's a program in Java that will perform this:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LargeTextFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
        try(BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("largeTextFile.txt"), charset)) {
            String s = "";
            // 100 kilobytes = 1024 bytes x 100 = 102400
            for(int i = 0; i < 102400; i++)
                // add random 0 or 1 to the string
                s += (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            // write to file
            writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
        } catch(IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```